# Netlogo random ycor

Tags: netlogo

How i can make a random ycor higher/lower than a value?I have traffic 2 sample and i added some sheeps on the grass but i want them to respawn and only on the grass randomly not on the road.And what should i change so that sheeps can`t never reach the streets?

```
breed [sheeps sheep]

to setup
  clear-all
  draw-road
  setup-vans
  create-or-remove-cars
  set selected-car one-of turtles
  ask selected-car [ set color red ]
  set selected-van one-of turtles
  ask selected-van [ set color red ]
  reset-ticks
  set-default-shape turtles "sheep"
  create-sheeps number-of-sheeps [ 
    set color white
    set xcor random-pxcor
    set ycor -4
    set energy random 10
  ]
end



to-report free [ road-patches ] ; turtle procedure
  let this-car self
  report road-patches with [
    not any? turtles-here with [ self != this-car ]
  ]
end



to go

  ask turtles [ move-forward ]

  ask turtles with [ ycor != target-lane ] [ move-to-target-lane ]
  ask sheeps
  [
    move
    forward 1
  ]
  tick
end
to move  
  rt random 100
  lt random 100
  fd 20
  set energy energy - 0.5
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two questions here.  Let me answer the first.

```
set ycor some-value + random-float (max-pycor + 0.5 - some-value)
```

where some-value is the value you want pycor to be greater than.  Similarly,

```
set ycor some-value - random-float (some-value - min-pycor - 0.5)
```

where some-value is the value you want pycor to be less than.
`max-pycor + 0.5` is the maximum possible value of ycor and `min-pycor - 0.5` is the minimum possible value.

Comment: I have an error while trying to use your code of line:There is already a turtle variabile called YCOR

Comment: Sorry, "let" should have been "set".  I edited my answer to correct it.

Comment: And how i can set them to be both in the same time(greater than something and lower than something in the same time)?maybe with a IF or something?Because my code takes the last line of code that i write

Comment: @NistorMihnea I don't understand what "greater than something and lower than something in the same time" is supposed to mean?